# find out the year of a UTC-date integer with javascript

Tags: javascript, date, utc

How could I find out the year of a UTC-date integer in javascript?
thnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your "UTC-date integer" represents a time in milliseconds:

```
var date = new Date(utcInteger);
console.log(date.getUTCFullYear());
```

Comment: oh man - I tried different approaches - why is this working now!? :-)

Comment: @headkit programming can be a bit like that sometimes, when that happens, step away from the machine and take a short break